# calendar in view in sharepoint disappeard

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, overlay

I have calendar List, in that I have added Overlay.
After that it will display on the left hand side of the screen under Calendars in View you will see the calendar overlay I created, Birthday.

[image]

Then I have edit default calendar.aspx in calendar, added **All Events** list view web part. 
Then I have find out that on the left hand side of the screen under Calendars in View you I can't see the calendar overlay I created, Birthday.

[image]

But When I removed **All Events** list view web part, then it will again start to display.
Please suggest some workaround.
or can I create custom **calendar in view** in using Java scripts or something.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. I added the All Events list view wp by editing the page, adding the site's Calendar App to the web part field and changed the view from the web part's properties. Is this the way you configured it as well?

Comment: are you added Calendar Overlay.

Comment: Yes, I tried with 2-3 overlays.

Comment: great, but it's not working on production site. currently it's working fine on my local machine

Comment: Are you running the same versions of SharePoint with both of your environment? Are there any masterpage customizations done to your production site's masterpage?

Comment: It don't seems like master-page issue

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in SharePoint Online and the only time I see the missing "Calendars in View" control on the page is immediately after having added the additional Calendar web part with the All Events View selected and saved the page.

If I then remove the following resulting querystring in the browser address bar

```
PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage
```

the page renders with the "Calendars in View" control once again on the page.

Comment: Erik, I have found the same result, so will you please suggest some workaround. or any idea how to create custom "Calendar in view" using scripts

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and only way to get back all the color coded and main calendar views is select the main calendar further down in left navigation as the blue main calendar under "Calendars in View" doesn't select anything.  I created another view to select "All" but then all disappears when selecting only one view. In other words, all the views disappear.  Also, when selecting each calendar overlay, the color changes back to blue, which confuses user. You also have to change the main calendar to not select a category, or it shows twice.  We also don't have an easy web part to add to top of calendar to add the main calendar url so the user can get the views back on the left of calendar.  Additionally, we can't send an email or invite from that calendar to Outlook.  Not even similar to a "Task" that can send an email.  I will try a Flow for the email, but this should be basic out-of-box feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this "feature" is unusable the way it is. Things disappear whenever anything is clicked... a group of users will never figure out how this works (I can't figure out what they were going for here).